# Write CSV file with Upper Case Header

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am trying to write a csv file but with upper case headers.
Entries is a collection of objects.

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(csvStream))
            {
                var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                {
                    PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.ToUpper()
                };
                using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, csvConfig))
                {
                    csvWriter.WriteRecords<T>(entries);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                }
           }
```

I can see the file has been written but headers are not in capital letter. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`PrepareHeaderForMatch` is for matching and mapping headers to your model when you want to `Read` a csv file not writing. for writing to csv file, you need to set `Name` attribute for your properties like this:

```cs
  public class CsvModel
    {
        [Name("NAME")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Name("FAMILY")]
        public string Family { get; set; }
    }
```

Or you can set header names in csv mapping:

```cs
public class CsvModelMap : ClassMap<CsvModel>
{
    public CsvModelMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Name).Index(0).Name("NAME");
        Map(m => m.Family).Index(1).Name("FAMILY");
    }
}
```

Comment: Writing name attribute with each property would be ok but is there no other way to set in the configuration?

Comment: I haven't seen before but maybe you should write an extension for the mapping and make upper case names.

Comment: *but is there no other way to set in the configuration?* - to achieve what, if `[Name` is "ok"?

Comment: @Saeed is the Map even needed?

Comment: @CaiusJard in case of using ``Name`` attribute no need to use map

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more generic approach to making all the headers uppercase, you can use the `Map(Type classType, MemberInfo member, bool useExistingMap = true)` overload of the `Map` method.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var records = new List<CsvModel>
    {
        new CsvModel { Name = "name", Family = "first" },
    };

    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var fooMap = new DefaultClassMap<CsvModel>();

        var properties = typeof(CsvModel).GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            fooMap.Map(typeof(CsvModel), property).Name(property.Name.ToUpper());
        }
        
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(fooMap);
        
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }
}

public class CsvModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
}
```